# Как настроить filebeat для чтения STDOUT и STDERR логов docker контейнера NGINX

Tags: nginx, docker, логирование, elasticsearch

Я использую [стандартный nginx Docker-образ](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) и Filebeat для чтения логов и дальнейшей их отправки ELK.
Оба контейнера (nginx контейнер и Filebeat контейнер) находятся на одной хост машине.

Ниже представлен Dockerfile для образа nginx

```
FROM nginx
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html/
EXPOSE 80
```

В моем nginx контейнере access log пишется в `STDOUT` и error log пишется `STDERR`.

Когда я на хост машине ввожу команду `docker logs <nginx-containter-id>` я могу увидеть логи из nginx контейнере.

Однако в каталоге контейнера на хост машине вообще нет логов (`/var/lib/docker/containers/nginx-container-id`)

Как я могу настроить filebeat для чтения логов?

Comment: у вас два абсолютно несвязанных вопроса. причём один ([явно малозначительный и элементарный](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33017329/4827341)) вынесен в заголовок. сконцентрируйтесь на том, что вас действительно интересует. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо, справедливое замечание!